# About FileReader code

Tags: java

I'm pretty new to when it comes to the FileReader pieces of code, writer is a bunch more simpler. But the question is, when it comes to the FileReader I need to read the .txt file and show specific pieces of data from the text file.

The format of the .txt file is like:

```
01 Jan 2018     1     2     12     Y     NS213B     515     N Summers

                      ^
                      |
```

I need the third columns data that is only 3 and 4 and place that into a variable. So it would display something like

```
System.out.println("Total number of 3 & 4s: " + numberOf3N4s);
```

output would show something like: Total number of 3 & 4s: 100

```
public static void displaySummaryofContracts()
{   
    String filePath = "contracts.txt";  //Change to either contracts.txt or archive.txt, only accesible files
    int numberOfContracts = 0;
    String arr[] = {"Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"};
    String space = "   ";

    try {
        try (BufferedReader lineReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath)))
        {
            String lineText = null;

            while ((lineText = lineReader.readLine()) != null) {
                numberOfContracts++;
            }
        }
    } 
    catch (IOException ex)
    {
        System.err.println(ex);
    }

    System.out.println("Total Number of Contracts: " + numberOfContracts);
    System.out.println("Number of contracts per Month:");
    System.out.println(arr[0] + space + arr[1] + space + arr[2] + space + arr[3] + space + arr[4]  + space + arr[5]  
             + space + arr[6] + space + arr[7] + space + arr[8] + space + arr[9] + space + arr[10] + space + arr[11]);
}
```

Comment: Write some code and share it with us. We are a helper, not an originator.

Comment: read the line then use split `String result = line.split("\\s{2,}")[2];`

Comment: split string by keeping 'tab' as delemiter -> String[] result = input.split("\t"); Third element (result[2]) will be your required column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your statement you need 3rd column. For each line in file, split the line into array of string with **tab** as deliter. In the retrieved array use 2nd element or verification. The try-catch statement can be written as follows:

```java
    ArrayList<String> savedLines = new ArrayList<String>();
    try (BufferedReader lineReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath)))
    {
        String lineText = null;

        while ((lineText = lineReader.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] split = lineText.split("\t"); 
            if(split[2].equals("3")||split[2].equals("4")){
                    savedLines.add(lineText);
                    numberOfContracts++;
            }


        }
    } 
    catch (IOException ex)
    {
        System.err.println(ex);
    }
```

Comment: Okay, so lets say just like within the total number of contracts. How would one be able to still choose the third columns data but only take the numbers 3 and above and have that within a System.out.println(""); outside of the try catch

Comment: is it like you need to exclude first 2 columns and print the rest ??

Comment: As the data from within the .txt file, the third columns data goes 1,2,3 or 4 as the possibilities. I then need to be able to take the data from that column which is 3 and 4 then display that in a System.out.println("info" + data);. Which basically says that the number of contracts that are 3 and 4 : (equals the amount there are that are 3 and 4).

Comment: In case the 3rd column is 3 or 4 you want to save that line ??

Comment: Yes that's what I need it to do

Comment: I have modified the code according to your requirements

Comment: Issue is, it outputs all of the contracts, instead of just the the number of 3 and 4s.

Comment: "all of the contracts" .. like entire line ??

Comment: Correct, instead of it just printing the amount of 3s and 4s from within the text file. It is printing the entire line that has 3 and 4. For example: number of ...  [04-Mar-2016 1 3 24 N MT962N 810 Z Gul, 21-Dec-2016 2 3 24 N MH202N 945 X Herzog,... I need it to be something like Number of Medium and Large  Contracts : (the amount)

Comment: Now i have placed  `numberOfContracts` variable in `if` block. This varialble contains amonunt of lines that contains 3 or 4 as 3rd column

Comment: That definitely explains a lot, thank you, I appreciate the help and the fact you hung in there to help me.

Comment: glad i could help :)

Comment: After several modifications my answer looks irrelevent to question. Is it possible to modify the question ??  If my answer is correct please accept my answer.

Comment: Does that make more sense?

Comment: Alright, apologies for the random reply again, but just thinking about what would the code looks like IF I was searching the text file for keywords like "N" it would output that entire line and all corresponding contracts. Or if they type Jan output the corresponding data that is related to Jan contracts. I require your wisdom again. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I didn't understand the "N" stuff but if it is Jan ... it will be present in `split[0]`(0th column). In loop the statement would be `if(split[0].contains("Jan"))savedLines.add(lineText);`

Comment: It took me an additional 30 minutes to figure out that to make it shorter I could just do "col[0].contains(selectedMonthInput)"

Comment: Now I just need to go back to the "if(split[2].equals("3")||split[2].equals("4")) " code and somehow put each month into an integer array and display the amount of contracts that are corresponding to that specific month

Comment: What is the size of your contract file ??

Comment: The contracts file is like 3KB as it holds like 200 contracts currently

Comment: did you seperate columns by tab or 5 spaces ??

Comment: this might be your code - https://drive.google.com/open?id=1-4mTJQ9TkqJWxexP4Svsm8Vy6_HKHT2l

Comment: issue is - https://docs.google.com/document/d/1zn_lJAL_0KH8-PFEFSGW9RsQB2IuOREcB8rIrG4vQKc